# Python Matplotlib x-axis improperly labels timedelta64 object

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a plot from a Pandas dataframe in Python with Matplotlib. Here is a summary of the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Summarize data frame.
>>> df.shape
(40, 4)

>>> df.dtypes
ID                         object
relative_time     timedelta64[ns]
value                     float64
relative_value            float64
dtype: object

>>> df.head()
    ID     relative_time  value  relative_value
0  001 -1 days +18:08:04    4.5            -1.0
1  001 -1 days +18:18:03    4.5            -1.0
2  001 -1 days +18:28:03    4.5            -1.0
3  001 -1 days +18:38:04    4.5            -1.0
4  001 -1 days +18:48:03    4.5            -1.0

>>> df.tail()
     ID     relative_time  value  relative_value
35  001 -1 days +23:58:03    5.5             0.0
36  001          00:08:03    5.5             0.0
37  001          00:18:03    5.5             0.0
38  001          00:28:02    5.5             0.0
39  001          00:38:04    5.5             0.0
```

I am trying to plot `relative_time` on the x-axis and `relative_value` on the y-axis. However, the code below produces an unexpected result, where I cannot what tell what units the x-axis is in.

```
# Plot the desired plot.
plt.plot(test['relative_time'], test['relative_value'], marker='.')
```

[image]

Note, the x-axis in the plot above is not in units of hours (relative to time 0). Such a plot would look like the following.

```
plt.plot(test['relative_time'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'h'), test['relative_value'], marker='.')
```

[image]

How can I plot the x-axis so that it displays time in the same format as the `relative_time` column? For example, if the x-axis were to have tick marks every hour, they would be labeled as, `-1 days +18:00:00`, `-1 days +19:00:00`, ...,  `00:00:00`, and `01:00:00`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The units of your x-axis are nanoseconds, as shown in your output

```
>>> df.dtypes
ID                         object
relative_time     timedelta64[ns]  <----- [ns] == nanoseconds
value                     float64
relative_value            float64
dtype: object
```

Looks like matplotlib just displays nanoseconds, so you need to format those nanoseconds to a string format. Unfortunately, the functionality around the `numpy.timedelta64` data type is limited and I couldn't find anything in the `numpy` documentation that could do that.

### Example [Formatted x-axis labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6bFP.png)

*Source:* [matplotlib intelligent axis labels for timedelta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240003/matplotlib-intelligent-axis-labels-for-timedelta)

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

Create an array of `np.timedelta64[ns]` values. This is what you would get if you did `df["relative_time"].values`.

```
# create list of times
x = [np.timedelta64(k, "ns") for k in range(0,300*10**9,10**9)]

# create some random y-axis data
y = np.random.random(len(x))

ax.plot(x, y)

# Function that formats the axis labels
def timeTicks(x, pos):
    seconds = x / 10**9 # convert nanoseconds to seconds
    # create datetime object because its string representation is alright
    d = datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)
    return str(d)

formatter = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(timeTicks)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you please edit to define `ax` before `ax.plot(x, y)`? The code as written returns a `NameError: name 'ax' is not defined`. You may also want to add `import matplotlib` at the top.

Comment: @Adam Done. Thanks.