# Cumulative plot from a Dataframe with only DateTime information

Tags: python, pandas, plot, cumulative-sum

I have a csv file like this:

```
2021-01-05 10:57:12.762000, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-05 10:58:26.622000, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-05 11:02:16.772000, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-05 11:02:34.042000, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-05 17:12:07.221999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 01:42:45.501999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 01:44:24.481999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 01:44:58.051999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 01:45:14.871999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 01:47:10.901999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 07:57:33.221999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 07:57:48.821999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 07:58:51.031999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 07:59:27.001999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 08:00:56.871999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 11:28:17.191999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 11:28:46.201999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 11:29:19.111999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 11:29:41.891999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 11:30:51.901999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 11:31:21.921999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 11:32:23.001999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-06 11:32:58.271999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-07 11:33:46.891999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-07 12:38:50.021999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-07 12:39:53.881999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-08 12:42:07.371999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-08 12:42:46.441999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
2021-01-09 12:44:14.291999, REDDE EHZ AM 00, trigger
```

I added the header with:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\Inves\SM\CC_Cbba\REDPy\OSCREDDE_3_\redde_3_trigs.dat',
                 sep=',', header=None, usecols=[0, 1, 2])
headers =  ["TrigDT", "Sta", "Type"]
```

The output is:

```
                       TrigDT               Sta      Type
0  2021-01-05 10:57:12.762000   REDDE EHZ AM 00   trigger
1  2021-01-05 10:58:26.622000   REDDE EHZ AM 00   trigger
2  2021-01-05 11:02:16.772000   REDDE EHZ AM 00   trigger
3  2021-01-05 11:02:34.042000   REDDE EHZ AM 00   trigger
4  2021-01-05 17:12:07.221999   REDDE EHZ AM 00   trigger
...
```

I created a Date colum in roder to try to group the information by days:

```
df['TrigDT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TrigDT'])
df['Date'] = df['TrigDT'].dt.date
```

I tried to have a cumulative sum with Index because I do not have a colum with counter of events, then I tried to group by days but I fail:

```
df = df.groupby('Date').index.sum()
df = df.groupby(df.index.day).cumsum().reset_index()
```

The idea is to create a cumulative plot with the DataFrame information (X axis with dates a Y axis with cumulative information), I tried to have a plot [like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895480/python-plot-timedelta-and-cumulative-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895480/python-plot-timedelta-and-cumulative-values)

Would you mind to give me some tips to reach the objective?, the expected output could be like this, in my case only with one station that is called REDDE:

[image]
Thank you

Comment: What' should be displayed on the Y axis? It seems a numerical column is missing... Could you add your expected output to the question?

Comment: Hi @Tranbi, I edited the question adding the image of the expected output, you are rigth, it is missing a numerical column, how can I generate it?, can be the index colum the one I need to plot the cumulative?

Comment: IIUC you want to display the normated count of rows? Something like `df['cumul_norm'] = df.index / len(df) * 100` could help you. What are a, b and c? Do you want one plot per `Sta` value? In that case might want to group your df first... Your question could benefit from more details anyway.

Comment: Hi @Tranbi, Yes the normated count of rows, a-b-c are station names, can not be grouped by only days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood what `a`, `b`, `c` would be exactly in your chart, but here is how you can accumulate the number of triggers daily:

```
# Load the data and set 'TrigDT' as the index
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_file.csv', header=None, usecols=(0, 1, 2), names=('TrigDT', 'Sta', 'Type'))    
df.TrigDT = pd.to_datetime(df.TrigDT)
df.set_index('TrigDT', inplace=True)

# Resample to daily and count
daily_acc = df.resample('d').count().cumsum()                                                    
daily_acc.plot()
```

Comment: hi @fsl, it works, a,b,c are the names of some stations that trigger detections, thanks